# Getting a list of applications and signers in Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to get a list of programs, their path in the file system, and their signatures. My current script returns the program and their path, but the signer field is left empty in all cases. What do I need to fix?

Script:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App 
Paths\*"  |
Where-Object {$_."(default)" -ne $null} |
Select-Object @{ expression={$_.PSChildName}; label='Program'} ,
@{expression={$q + $_."(default)" +$q}; label='Path'}, 
@{expression={Get-AuthenticodeSignature $_.("default") }; label='Signer'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Signer your parenthesis are on the wrong side of the quotes.

Use:

```
@{expression={Get-AuthenticodeSignature $_."(default)" }; label='Signer'}
```

You can also get more information on the certificate(such as the issuer) like this:

```
@{expression={$(Get-AuthenticodeSignature $_."(default)").SignerCertificate.Issuer }; label='Signer'}
```